# How to access a property in array of objects without looping through all of them in php?

Tags: php

Is it possible to access a property inside array of objects that all objects have? 
Lets say i have

```
array(
  [0] => {
    [id] = 5,
    [name] = 'Name'
    [everyobjecthasme] = sameforall
  }, 

  [1] = >{
    [id] = 6
    [name] = 'Name2'
    [everyobjecthasme] = sameforall
  }
)
```

Is it possible to access the property everyobjecthasme (which is universal for all objects) in array of this objects without looping since i need only one object to get this property in php?

Comment: Can you just check element 1?

Comment: Do you know the exact way to it? I.e. the array you posted above - `$array['everyobjecthasme']`..?

Comment: How to check the element 1 in array of objects without looping? Please read the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your objects all have the property 'everyobjecthasme' you could do something like this:

```
$obj1 = new stdClass;
$obj1->everyobjecthasme = 'sameforall';
$obj2 = new stdClass;
$obj2->everyobjecthasme = 'sameforall';
// add objects to array
$array = array(
    0=>$obj1,
    1=>$obj2,
);
// access first object's property
echo $array[0]->everyobjecthasme;
```

Comment: It is an array of objects, not array of arrays. This gives error 'Cannot use object of type stdClass as array'.

Comment: Of course it's simple. I feel silly now :) Thank you for your solution.